# Does turning on/off GPS broadcast the android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED message?

Tags: android

On Froyo:

When turning on and off the GPS, is the android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED message supposed to be broadcast? I have an application that turns the GPS on and off, and a listener is set for this message (to verify that the action occurred), and the listener is never called even though the GPS is being enable and disabled. Because I have to use a hack to programatically control the GPS, I'm wondering if I should be broadcasting this message myself.

Launcher Pro is seeing that I'm toggling the state of the GPS, and it changes it's widget icons appropriately, so I'm not sure if I need to send the message. In which case the message is being sent and I'm not listening for the message properly (but if I send it myself the receiver does respond). Or I'm not listening for the correct message.

On a related note, in which source code modules should I look to see when the PROVIDERS_CHANGED message is being broadcast?

Answer (score 3):

In the [Android Location Manager reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION), you can see that the constant for **android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED** has been added since `API Level 9` ( = Android 2.3).

Froyo = Android 2.2 = `API Level 8`

That explains why the intent is never fired on Froyo.